# Does scikit learn's fit_transform also transform my original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learning's StandardScaler() and notice that after I apply a transform(xtrain) or fit_transform(xtrain), it also changes my xtrain dataframe. Is this supposed to happen? How can I avoid the StandardScaler from changing my dataframe? ( I have tried using copy=False)

```
xtrain.describe()    #everything ok here
scalar = StandardScaler()
xtrain2 = scalar.fit_transform(xtrain)
```

At this stage, I would expect xtrain to NOT have changed while xtrain2 to be a scaled version of xtrain. But when I run describe() on the 2 dataframes, I see they are both the same and both have been scaled. Why is that?

I experience the same problem when I do:

```
scalekey = scalar.fit(xtrain)
xtrain2 = scalekey.transform(xtrain)
```

Comment: What version sklearn, numpy and pandas are you using the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) state that the default param of `copy=True` should mean that it returns a copy rather than performing the scaling inplace

Comment: I can't reproduce your error using pandas 0.16.2, python 3.3.4 64-bit, numpy 1.9.2 and sklearn 0.16.1

Comment: @EdChum, I have had the problem described by Jason with pandas 0.14.x and sklearn 0.15.x. It is one of the cross-interactions between the libraries that has apparently been fixed in later versions (like issues with cross validation).

Comment: @EdChum, I am using sklearn 0.15.2, pandas 0.15.2, numpy 1.9.2, Python 2.7.9 in Anaconda 2.2.0 (64 bit). Thank you for your solution below, it works. 
I am starting to think it is because my xtrain is a view of my original dataframe, so the transform affects it..

xtrain, xtest = dfX[idx], dfX[idx==False]

Comment: Hi, I took a view of a slice of my df and I still cannot reproduce your problem, I'd try upgrading pandas and sklearn, another thing to try is whether `xtrain2 = scalar.fit_transform(xtrain.values) ` modifies the df or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a copy and pass this in order to not modify your df:

```
xtrain2 = xtrain.copy()
scalar.fit_transform(xtrain2)
```

The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) state that the default param for `StandardScaler` is that `copy=True` so it should not have modified your df.

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading to 0.16.x or higher in both pandas and scikit-learn. The package authors are constantly improving the way each package treats the other.